# What is a fast way to check whether each of 10M strings is in a list of 4000 other strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list `block_list` of 4000 blocked domain names. I need to check each string in a pandas series `inspection_list["string"]` of 10M strings to see if the string is a blocked domain name. If so, mark it `True`, else `False`

There's gotta be a faster or parallelizable way better than:

```
for i, r in inspection_list.iterrows()
     if r["string"] in inspection_list:
          inspection_list["blocked"][i] = True
     else:
          inspection_list["blocked"][i] = False
```

Comment: Is `inspection_list` an actual list, or a dictionary, or something else?  (you really want it to be a dictionary, or something else with O(log(n)) average lookup time or less -- if `inspection_list` is a Python list or similar, then you're suffering an O(n) lookup time on each iteration of your for-loop, which is going to make things really slow)

Comment: I made this question to share the time comparison below. In this case I made both a pandas DataFrame. I had this problem and wanted to make it easy for someone looking for this solution or considering it to see that isin() is a very fast (relative to this solution) way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.series.isin() proved a lot faster than a pandas apply. The loop given above I didn't even let complete after it took more than 30 seconds.

On a subset of 500k rows:

```
%%time
check["blocked"]=check["domain"].isin(blocked["domain"])
```

**Wall time: 48.4 ms**

```
%%time
check["blocked"]=check["domain"].apply(lambda x: True if x in blocked["domain"] else False)
```

**Wall time: 6.49 s**